# Using JSONPath to find an object based on one of its properties

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

Given the following JSON structure, I want to be able to find the entry in the `$.data` array that contains an item with a specific `itemId`.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "items": [{"itemId": "item1"}]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "items": [{"itemId": "item2"}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's say I'm looking for the entry with an `itemId == "item2"` - in which case I want to extract the full object:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "items": [{"itemId": "item2"}]
}
```

I've attempted nesting `$()` filters, but to no avail:

```
$.data[?@.items[?(@.itemId == "item2")])]
$.data[?("item2" in @.items[*].itemId)]
$.data[?(@.items[*].itemId contains "item2")]
```

I can easily find the "item" object itself, through `$.data[*].items[?(@.itemId == "item2")]`, but I'd like to actually retrieve its parent object! Is this even possible with JSONPath?

Comment: [Jayway JSONPath (A Java DSL)](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) supports additional filter operator like `in` and `contains`. Try here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Which library/implementation of JSONPath are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In this specific example, this should work:

```
$..data[?(@.items[0].itemId == 'item2')]
```

Result is a list, because filters always return lists:

```
[
  {
    "id": "2",
    "items": [
      {
        "itemId": "item2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This works here because we're taking the first element in the `items` array in order to apply the filter (index `[0]`). For a more complex scenario, some tweaking may be needed.

Tested here: https://jsonpath.com/